# Using node-inspect with inquirer

Tags: node.js, node-inspector, inquirerjs

I am trying to use node-inspect to debug an application that uses [inquirer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/inquirer). If I run:

```
node app.js
```

I get asked the first question for my app. I then use the keyboard to enter my answer and hit enter to continue.

My issue is when

1. Run `node-inspect app.js`
2. Open debug URL in Chrome
3. Hit continue in Chrome to start script execution
4. See the first question appear in terminal
5. Enter my response in terminal and press enter

I am expecting this to continue to the next question as per the first example, however, I cannot get terminal to recognise any input from the keyboard.

I am on a Mac.